# sending data in Post Method from Android Client to Java Servlet

Tags: android, http, servlets, http-post, httpresponse

I implement client server code with java android. the problem is I couldn't be able to connect to servlet. Where is my problem? Here is my code:

**android code**: 
....

```
HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost getMethod=new HttpPost("http://" + Server + "/RestaurantServer/Login");

try {
    // Add your data
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Mode", "Login"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName",txtusername.getText().toString() ));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",txtpassword.getText().toString() ));

    getMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    client.execute(getMethod);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and server side:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        String mode=request.getParameter("Mode");
        if ("Login".equals(mode)) {
            String userName= request.getParameter("userName");
            String password= request.getParameter("password");
            System.out.println("post method: "+userName + "! pass :"+password);
            user = new User(password,userName);
            if (UserDao.authenticate(user)==true)
                out.write("Accept".toString());
            else
                out.write("Wrong".toString());
        } else if ("Register".equals(mode)) {
            String userName= request.getParameter("userName");
            String password= request.getParameter("password");
            String name= request.getParameter("name");
            String email= request.getParameter("email");
            String address= request.getParameter("address");
            String phoneNumber= request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
            System.out.println("reg mod: "+userName + "! pass :"+password);
            user = new User(userName,password,name,email,address, phoneNumber);

            if (UserDao.addUser(user) == true)
                out.write("Added");
            else
                out.write("NotAdded");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method name from processRequest() to doPost() and check your mapping in web.xml.May be the Servlet and URL mapping is not correct.Send your web.xml and the name of Servlet.

Comment: At the begining: i write this:@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/Login"})       I called processRequest in doPost method: @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

Comment: then there might be a problem in your mapping.post your web.xml